lwip UDP, CPU time consuming in stm32 boards
I am sending raw data using lwip library, udp protocol,RAW API.my evaluation board is stm32 F429zi.
The problem is when i send 48 bytes using udp_send() function, as i measured by oscilloscope, it takes 12 microseconds to return from this function! Which it means the freqeuncy for sending these data cannot be more than 72khz!
Is this a regular timing or something went wrong?
I expected to send these 48 bytes in a 8us time window or less.

It is not clear what you have measured with an oscilloscope.  Activity on the wire probably bares no resemblance to time spent in a function as there will be hardware buffering.  Your measurement may also not scale linearly so your conclusion on the effective throughput may be inaccurate. You have provided no information on the system clock rate you are running the MCU at, or what other interrupts or threads that may be preempting your transmission.  Network latency is in any event affected by other network traffic.  I doubt that you can draw any concrete conclusions from your observations

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Clock rate is 84mhz. There is no interrupt or another task or function preempting the function.

Clock rate is 84mhz. There is no interrupt or another task or function preempting the function. The code consist of a infinite while loop, in which i only assign a value in pbuf and then send the pbuf by udp_send function. I measure the time of udp_send execution by turning on a special pin before udp_send and turning it off after the function. The length of data i want to send by udp in each turn is 48 bytes.

Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help]. -- Please [edit] your question to add new information and to clarify. This is not a forum. -- You might want to add a [mre] showing the issue.
